# How should I handle failing tests caused by external dependencies?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, testng, test-strategy, external-dependencies

I have a situation where an dependent application is down and I cannot execute the test case. The test execution is automated. The test first calls the dependent application API and this API returns a 500 server error, causing the test to fail. We are using TestNG as test runner.

- Should my test script fail the test or is it better to skip the test?
- Should each failed test represent a defect in the Application under test?

Comment: Your post subject and post content are two different questions. What is the question you want to get an anwser for?

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite the question a bit to make it more clear. I think the two questions are close related and grouped it into a new question: How to handle test fails caused by external dependencies. @user2048204 please let us know if I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should it represent a defect in the Application under test?

No, it might be working, but you cannot verify. You do need to monitor and follow it up somehow. Therefore ignoring/[skipping](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng) the test-method and create a task in your workflow-system might make sense, but this could lead to a lot of waste handling and monitoring these issues. Do make sure you fix the issues as soon as possible, as test not run tend to grow old fast.

**It should fail**:

Sounds like you are writing end-to-end tests, I would expect this to test the application works end-to-end including external dependencies. Skipping them would give a false sense of security.

If you do not want to be alarmed by a test you know is failing due to external dependencies out of your control I would mute them. The tests should still run, but should not report their failure until either:

- They run successful once, which removes the mute status
- The muted time range expired, I would mute tests for some days and then re-evaluate if the mute is still correct.

Our build-server [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) supports muting out-of-the-box, for other build-servers you might need to build something yourself. Worst case you add a ignore flag to the test-method and put an item in your agenda to un-ignore them.

**Muting best practises**:

- Always use a time range, never mute it forever!
- Document why it was muted
- Have cycle where you check muted (also ignored/skipped) tests regularly
- Plan action to remove the mute

Comment: +1 Good option (as usual).  In the US we would probably use the term 'pause' over mute as mute doesn't suggest restarting at some point and pause does (not 100% but suggests).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I used the terminology that TeamCity uses, I do think that maybe pausing sounds better, but muting is more like snoozing, you do not stop the process you just ignore it temporary. Pausing sounds like stopping it totally.

Comment: No worries.  I think of pause as in a performance is paused.  To me that implies it will start again.  When I think of mute I don't think that of it as something that implies it will "unmute" as some point.  "The music was loud so I muted it" seems self contained without the future implication.  These may be cultural differences though. I am in north-east US culture currently.  I've never heard the term mute in the last 5 years of QE

Comment: "Mute" also feels like test continue to be run on the background but any output (failures) is ignored - is it what is happening? And "PASS" will un-mute test automagically. "Paused" test feels like they are waiting to be restarted (they do not progress, do not run at all). Good names are hard.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. Test keep running and get magically un-muted when they pass again.